# How to set Start of Hour using Moment js

Tags: javascript, arrays, momentjs, lodash

I'm trying to set the start of the hour to 9:15 AM, which is the Indian Share market start time. And I've to group the 15Min chart to hourly chart(9:15-10:15,10:15-11:15...) as below.

```
_.groupBy(dataset, (result) => moment(result[0]).startOf('hour').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM'));
```

but as the start of the hour is 9:15** and moment sets the start of hour to 00-60, not getting expected result.

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know what you want, but startOf('hour') in moment will always return to you the start of the hour in the moment that you instantiate. E.g.: if you create an moment from now (without parameters) you will get 02:51 (here, Brazil), if you ask for startOf(hour) you will get 02:00. I think, if you want to get xx:15, you can add 15 minutes after got startOf(hour) of your moment

```js
const m = moment().startOf('hour').add(15, 'minutes').format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');;
console.log(m)
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi Filipe, thanks for the response, but I achieved it through chunk method in lodash after grouping it by day.